# Can 'unexpectedAlertBehaviour' be set in ChromeDriver and Firefox as well as in IEDriverServer

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to set unexpectedAlertBehaviour to 'ignore' but can only find java examples for IEDriverServer.

Would prefer Ruby examples.

Comment: can you give the Java link that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necessity required me to figure out the answer to my own question

```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer(
      :unexpectedAlertBehaviour => 'ignore'
  )
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(:ie, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported. See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3392#c47; see also: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=537&q=unexpected&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary